# Which font is similar to Georgia, licensed free for trade books?

Tags: fonts, font-licensing, free, open-source

Looking at the [Georgia font license](https://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/georgia/licenses), you can see that it is not free for trade publications.

I want to publish a commercial book using a font similar to Georgia, but with a **free license**.

Does anyone know of a font with this feature?

The type of publication is a trade book, which will be printed at IngramSpark (print on demand).

Comment: Georgia is one of the default fonts pre-installed on Windows computers.  So if it came pre-installed on your computer, you already have a licence to use it. There is nothing in the Desktop EULA that prohibits its use in any kind of publication, commercial or otherwise.

Comment: @BillyKerr i'm not working with computer in Windows, i'm using Linux (Ubuntu). At Google Fonts, Georgia appears with the trade-mark (R)  with the note: *No matches in the open source catalog.* For write the document i will use LaTeX.

Comment: Gerogia is a pretty basic serif font. There are lots that are similar.  Have a look at Linux Libertine/Libertinus fonts available from fontlibrary.org

Comment: Also there are hundreds of serif fonts on google fonts you can look through: https://fonts.google.com/?category=Serif

Comment: There are over 400 [serif fonts at fontlibrary](https://fontlibrary.org/en/search?category=serif&order=)

Answer (score 0):

The most similar free font to Georgia is probably Neuton on Google Fonts. They look very similar except that Georgia has a nicer-looking serif at the tops of letters like C and G. The J in Georgia is also rounded up, while the J in Neuton has a short descender. If you are not wedded to using the free font that looks most similar to Georgia then, as others have pointed out, there are plenty of other options that may look better.

The license tab for Neuton on Google Fonts says "These fonts are licensed under the Open Font License. You can use them freely in your products & projects - print or digital, commercial or otherwise. This isn't legal advice, please consider consulting a lawyer and see the full license for all details."

I hope this is still useful even though you asked the question a while ago.